# Is it possible to create a state object by doing a replaceState()?

Tags: javascript, pushstate

I'm asking this because I'm on a situation where I will call multiple Ajax request and I don't especially want to send a new object every time to a different state.

So I **create** my new history through `history.replaceState(stateObj, "", "mypage");`

And later I'll do `history.replaceState(NEWstateObj, "", "mypage");`

Is this correct, and does the object would be edited?

A secondary question could be : If I update my object and send it threw pushState() would it affect only the next state or create a new history each time (this is the problem I want to avoid).

It is sadly not specify on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) and I'd like to know before going in this development.